# What percentage of users use the /questions page to view questions?

Tags: discussion, statistics, navigation

There are two primary ways to view questions:

- [The questions link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions) (clicking the "questions")
- [The homepage link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) (clicking the site name icon or from the base url)

My question is what the total page views for each of those pages are, for all the different SE sites?

I have wondered often about this, because there are different functionality from the SE engine on sites for those two pages. It'd be helpful knowledge for future feature requests, especially if the data is split logged in vs not-logged-in users.

There is also the /active link too which I would be curious in, too. I'm not sure if it's a "primary way" or not - maybe this would help me understand :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that will vary with the size of the site. For Meta.SO and Meta.SE, with their reduced traffic, I almost always use /questions. Not so on SO proper. I also use /questions on places I lurk, like Signal Processing.

Comment: What is the difference between home and /questions?

Comment: I use both, plus watching specific tags, depending on what I feel like doing while on the site. It's a single data point, but it may not be as clear cut as X% use the home page and Y% use the questions page.

Comment: I always use /questions on my main sites (Arqade and meta.se), I only use the homepage when I want to learn something new